# Retrieving individuals with given condition in the same date

Tags: r, date, group-by

I have the following data:

```
df = id Date Medication
1  2020-02-10     A       
1  2020-02-10     B       
1  2020-03-10     C         
2  2020-05-30     A          
2  2020-05-10     B            
2  2020-05-10     C
3  2020-07-10     A
3  2020-07-10     B
3  2020-07-10     C
4  2020-09-01     A
4  2020-09-10     B
4  2020-09-10     C
```

I would like to extract those unique individuals with medication A and B on the same date. In this example, would be only id 1 (A and B given on the 2020-02-10) and 3 (A and B given on the 2020-05-10).

Comment: For the correct groups, do you need the entire group? or just observations A and B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id, Date) %>%
   filter(all(c("A", "B") %in%  Medication), Medication %in% c("A", "B")) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
     id Date       Medication
  <int> <chr>      <chr>     
1     1 2020-02-10 A         
2     1 2020-02-10 B         
3     3 2020-07-10 A         
4     3 2020-07-10 B
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I think you are missing id in group_by so that it groups by id and Date: group_by(id, Date)

Comment: @Economist_Ayahuasca thanks.  I updated.  I guess your data showed could even work without the 'id' in the grouping (maybe not in your original data)

Answer (score 4):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(Date[Medication == "A"] == Date[Medication == "B"])
```